# When is the top user generated?

Tags: feature-request, reputation-leagues, top-users

In the top-user page by tag we can see

> Only non community-wiki questions and answers are included in these totals (updated daily)

But we don't know when. 1 hour ago or 23 hours ago. It could be interesting to have this information on this page. The hour when it was generated or the time between the generation was..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my experience and observation, the top user list is generated around midnight [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). A timestamp would be nice, or just an update to the text like `(updated daily around midnight UTC)`.

Comment: yes, I suppose the same time, but can't be sure. Add this simple text can be useful and not really hard to do.